# Probability of drawing 3 aces 3 times in a row with replacement

Tags: probability, card-games

I was playing a game using $7$ cards (one for each player), and there were $2$ aces in those cards. Each person would draw a card every round, and and then we would give them back for another shuffle (replacement). In the first two rounds, I got an ace twice, and in the third round I said that there would be a very low chance for me to get an ace for the third time in a row. However, someone said "You are just as likely to get an ace as me". I understand that that person was considering the probability
$$P(\text{3rd ace | 2 aces in a row}) = \frac{2} {7}, $$
while I was considering
$$P(\text{getting 3 aces in a row}) = \left(\frac{2} {7}\right) ^3. $$

My question would be who had the right reasoning in the situation: me, him, or are we both right due to the probability space each considers?

Comment: I'd say your friend was correct because the circumstances when he made his statement were such that you had indeed already drawn two aces. $(\frac{2}{7})^3$ is the probability of getting 3 aces in a row before any rounds have already been played.

Comment: If everyday you drive a car on road where the probability to get an accident is $\frac{1}{1000}$. After $999$ days have passed (with no accident), does it mean the next time you take this road you are much more likely to have an accident?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have been trapped in the [gambler's fallacy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy)!

You shuffle the deck at every round so the probability to fish an ace at the n-th round (after the results of the other rounds are already established) doesn't depend on what already happened earlier.

So , the first probability is the right one, you can see also that  :

$$P( \text {n-th  ace  in the n-th round  | n-1 aces  in  a  row }) =  P( \text{n-th ace in the n-th round} ) = \frac{2}{7}$$

Instead **at the start of the game** to fish an ace for $n$ consecutive round is equal to $(\frac{2}{7})^n$. But this just because nothing happened yet!